# Enabling CORS Google Cloud Function (Error 500) (Python-Flask)

Tags: python, angular, typescript, flask, google-cloud-platform

Im trying to deploy a flask app in google cloud, but i have a problem with CORS.

i add the headers to my function but now i have a Error 500

[image: Error 500]
:

[image]
and when i see the google cloud logs this error appear. Should i change something in the frontend? or i implement wrong the cors in the backend. this is my first deploy of a web app so every tip you give me i would aprecciate it!

Register Method:

[image]

---

Login Method:
[image]
this is my backend code:

```py
        @app.route('/user/login', methods=['POST'])
    def login(request):
    
      
        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        
            headers = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
            }
            return ('', 204, headers)
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    
    
        email=request.get_json()['email']
        password=request.get_json()['password']
        result=""
    
        response_user=user_database_service.get_user(email)
    
        if response_user:
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(response_user.password, password):
                access_token=create_access_token(
                    identity=
                    {
                        'first_name': response_user.first_name,
                        'last_name': response_user.last_name,
                        'email': response_user.email
                    }
                )
                result=jsonify({'token': access_token})
            else:
                result=jsonify({'error': 'Invalid username or password'})
        return (result, 200, headers)
```

and this is how i call my api in the frontend

```js
     public login(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any>
      {
        const base=this.http.post<TokenResponse>(`https://premierleagueapi.nn.r.appspot.com/user/login`, user)
        const request=base.pipe(
        map((data: TokenResponse) => {
            if(data.token)
            {
              this.saveToken(data.token)
            }
            console.log(data)
            var x = JSON.stringify(data)
            console.log("Este es x: " + x)
            if ( x == '{"error":"Invalid username or password"}')
            {
              Swal.fire({
                title: 'Login Invalido',
                text: "Haz ingresado la contraseña incorrecta",
                icon: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Reintentar'})
            }
            
    
            return data
          })
        )
        console.log("Request: " + request)
        return request
        
      }
```

Comment: It is important to correctly format Python code in your question. Your code does not show the code that failed (`/user/register`).

Comment: @JohnHanley i have te same problem in every method but i updated the question thanks